# Jess plugin for eclipse not working?and not installed

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jess

Here are the steps I have followed to install the Jess plugin:

1) Install eclipse ide (Oxygen).

2) Download java expert system shell (jess) from http://www.jessrules.com/jess/download.shtml

3) Extract the downloaded file.

4) You will find inside the extracted folder a folder named eclipse, open it.

5) Extract the 5 archives in it.

6) You now have 2 folders features and plugins, move them to eclipse directory.

The plugin does not show up in eclipse.

Are there any other steps? Do I also need to add the jess jars to my system path? Is there any other way to install the jess in eclipse?

Comment: Just copying things into Eclipse directories hasn't been a supported way of installing things for a very long time. Try starting Eclipse with the `-clean` option.

Answer (score 0):

The Jess plugins for Eclipse do not work with modern versions of Eclipse; they worked with Juno and probably not since then. I’ve actually been updating them in my spare time and hope to make the new versions available soon.

Comment: Jess rules are just text — use the text editor in Eclipse or whatever environment you use. Alternatively if you’re an Emacs user, there’s a Jess emacs-mode — see links on Jess web site.